# How to Make NetBeans Navigator Go to Java Constructor Source

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Windows 7 and NetBeans 7.1.1.

The NetBeans Navigator window will list all the methods in a Java class, including its constructor:

[image]

If I right-click on a method and select "Go to source," the IDE jumps the editor window's cursor to the source for that method. Except that this doesn't work for the class constructor itself. The "Go to source" menu option still appears when I right-click the constructor name, but selecting that item does nothing.

How do I jump to a Java class's constructor source from the NetBeans Navigator window?

Comment: It is working fine in 7.0.1. Not sure why it is not in 7.1.1. May be restart and check.

Comment: Works for me on 7.1.1. You can also double click.

Comment: Works also on 7.1.2 btw instead of `right click`->`go to source` you can use `double left click`

Comment: Heh. You guys are right. It's working now, after a restart. Utterly baffling.